# How to add a live `directory ` template to PyCharm's `New` context menu?

Tags: intellij-idea, contextmenu, pycharm

In PyCharm, right clicking a folder in the "Project" hierarchy or pressing `Alt + Insert` will pop-up a context menu like the below image.

[image: PyCharm "New" Context Menu]

For my projects, i create modules, and their base structure has many files.  So how do i add a "Directory Template" in the context menu.  Just like the "Python Package" there.  In example:

In addition to `File`, `Directory` and `Python Package`, i need a `Base Module` entry there that will create the following folders:

```
__openerp__.py
__init__.py
|-xml
  |-foo.xml
  |-bar.xml
|-static
  |-egg.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no feature in PyCharm that would allow you to set this up through the UI. You can write a plugin that will create the necessary structure for you. PyCharm plugins are written in Java; see [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/PluginDevelopment) for plugin development documentation.

Comment: Ahaha, at least i know there really is None and great idea.  Alright, i'll take the advice. :)